# help with differential equations and local minimum

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, maxima-minima

I have this differential equation: $y'=-1+2xy$. I am asked to identify a curve that contains all possible minimum points of the various solution curves. Now I have no idea how to do this. The most I have done so far is set it to zero and I get $y=\frac{1}{2x}$. But I am not too sure how to use this or how to continue.

Comment: $\mathrm{y}\left(\,x\,\right) = {\mathrm{u}\left(\,x\,\right) \over x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What must be true about a function if it is differentiable and has a minimum? Fermat tells us the derivative is zero.

In this problem, you are given the derivative of any curve that solves the ode. You set it equal to zero and found the curve containing all of these potential minima. You are done.

Comment: Moreover the second derivative is $2y+2xy'=x+2x(-1+1)=x$, so the minima in are in the first quadrant (unless I made a calculation error, which is quite possible).

Comment: @Ian I graphed it and yes the minimum are in the first quadrant, but I am a bit lost. Then is what I did the most that can be done in this case?

Comment: @Pam_22R The minima are along $y=\frac{1}{2x},x>0$; the maxima are along $y=\frac{1}{2x},x<0$.

Comment: @Ian is this because for x>0 we will always have positive values?

Comment: No, it's because $y''$ is positive there (again assuming I didn't make a calculation error).